# Google Tag Manager script not saving in Cloud Page header

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We are attempting to embed a GTM, Google Tag Manager, script into the header of the Cloud Page header. When we do this and go to save the change CloudPages won't save it. We can take the GTM code out and it will save, so it may be a functionality issue with cloud pages since it won't accept the GTM script code.

Right now the GTM code is wrapped in  a $(document).load() because that was the only way we could get cloud pages to save it, and it kicks out an error and doesn't work.

Anyone have a similar issue or may have a solution?